# Pass echo php in javascript

Tags: javascript, php

As per question I implemented a dynamic form in javscript, which requires that the first option selected within a select matches another in a new select:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Documento senza titolo</title>
        <script>
            function random_function()
            {
                var a=document.getElementById("input").value;
                if(a==="INDIA")
                {
                    var arr=["Maharashtra","Delhi"];
                }
                else if(a==="USA")
                {
                    var arr=["Washington","Texas","New York"];
                }

                var string="";

                for(i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
                {
                    string=string+"<option>"+arr[i]+"</option>";
                }
                string="<select name='any_name'>"+string+"</select>";
                document.getElementById("output").innerHTML=string;
            }
        </script>
</head>
    <body>
        <select id="input" onchange="random_function()">
            <option>select option</option>
            <option>INDIA</option>
            <option>USA</option>
        </select>
        <div id="output">

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

up to here nothing strange, but now I was wondering, having previously created a db, how can I do instead of cities in a static way to implement `<?php echo $row_regioni['regione']; ?>`?

```
<select>
<?php do { ?>
<option>
<?php echo $row_regioni['regione']; ?>
</option>
<?php } while ($row_regioni = mysqli_fetch_assoc($regioni)); ?>
</select>
</form>
```

Comment: You won't be able to access `$row_regioni['regione']` with do-while logic, as the variable isn't set in the first iteration. Start the loop with `while ($row_regioni = mysqli_fetch_assoc($regioni))` and then you can access the array

Comment: @tshimkus ok, can you give a written example?

Answer (score 0):

The code for the html is the following.

```
<select>
    <?php
    while(($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($regioni)) !== null){
        print(
            "<option value='".htmlentities($row['regione'])."'>".
                htmlentities($row['regione']).
            "</option>"
         );
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

For passing it to javascript there are multiple solutions. The easiest (which I would not choose because of messing up javascript with php) is:

```
<?php
    $regions = array();
    while(($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) !== null){
        array_push($regions, '"'.str_replace('"', '\\"', $row['regione']).'"');
    }
?>
<script>regions = [<?php print(implode(",\n\t", $regions)); ?>];</script>
```

This will set the array `regions` which is then accessable in javascript. You can modify your js code to:

```
function random_function(){
    // ... 
    var string = "";
    for(var i = 0; i < regions.length; i++){
        string += "<option value='" + regions[i] + "'>" + regions[i] + "</option>";
    }
    string = "<select name='any_name'>" + string + "</select>";
    //...
}
```

Your example then looks like this:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Documento senza titolo</title>
    <?php
        $regions = array();
        while(($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) !== null){
            array_push($regions, '"'.str_replace('"', '\\"', $row['regione']).'"');
        }
    ?>
    <script>regions = [<?php print(implode(",\n\t", $regions)); ?>];</script>
    <script>
        function random_function(){
          var a = document.getElementById("input").value;
          var arr;
          
          if(a === "INDIA"){
            arr = ["Maharashtra", "Delhi"];
          }
          else if(a === "USA"){
            arr = ["Washington", "Texas", "New York"];
          }
          
          var options = "";
          
          for(var i = 0; i < regions.length; i++){
            options += "<option value='" + regions[i] + "'>" + regions[i] + "</option>";
          }
          
          var select ="<select name='any_name'>" + options + "</select>";
          document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = select;
        }
      </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <select id="input" onchange="random_function()">
      <option>select option</option>
      <option>INDIA</option>
      <option>USA</option>
    </select>
    <div id="output">

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I would prefere to create the select with php. If this is not possible I would use an ajax request to get the values from the database. But I am assuming you are not very familiar with js so I will not post the code for this. Those is advanced techniques.

Comment: error syntax:  array_push($regions, '"'.str_replace('"', '\\"', $row['regione'].'"')));

Comment: Yes, I am sorry. There is one ``)`` too much. I removed it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
<select id="input">
  <option value="">select option</option>
  <?php foreach(mysqli_fetch_assoc($regioni) as $region){ ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $region['regione']; ?>"><?php echo $region['regione']; ?></option>
  <?php } ?>
</select>
```

If you need set default value for selector, you can compare with some variable or string

```
<option value="<?php echo $region['regione']; ?>"<?php ($region['regione'] == 'INDIA') ? echo 
 ' selected="selected"' : '' ?>><?php echo $region['regione']; ?></option>
```